# why is the expected number of wins in mosteller's 2nd answer for "successive wins" 2c+f?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

The "Successive Wins" problem in Mosteller's book 50 challenging problems in probability has a second answer that is often overlooked. The problem is as follows.
To encourage her daughter, Sara, her mom offers her a grant money if she wins (at least) two tennis sets in a row in a three set series to be played against her mom and the champ of the tennis club alternately. Mom-Champ-Mom or Champ-Mom-Champ, according Sara's choice. The cham is a better player than her mom. Which series should Sara choose?

We denote the probability of winning a set against mom, is $m$, whereas the probability of winning a set against the Champ is $c.$

The second answer is as follows.

> We have a tendency to suppose that the higher the expected number of sucesses, the higher the probability of winning a prize, and often this supposition is useful. In our problem the expected number of wins under Champ-Mom-Champ is 2*c+m, which is less than the expected number of wins for Mom-Champ-Mom, 2*m +c.

My question is why is the expected number of wins 2*c+m for Champ-Mom-Champ ... how does Mosteller come up with this, and why is the expected number of wins for Mom-Champ-Mom is 2*m+c?

It can't be as simple as Champ-Mom-Champ = c+m+c = 2*c + m (?! How does this even follow as expected number of wins), and analogously for Mom-Champ-Mom  = m+c+m = 2*m+c. (This can't be right.)

So, how do we proceed on this?

Comment: Expectation is linear.  But I;m not sure how computing the expectation helps you solve the underlying problem.  My bias would have me prefer $C-M-C$ since, with $M-C-M$ you'll probably lose the middle game which kills you.

Comment: Mosteller has the comment, many of us have a tendency to suppose that the higher the expected number of  sucesses the higher the probability of winning a prize and often this supposition is useful. 
It's Mosteller that proposed this thought as a second potential argumentative solution. My question is I'm not sure how he came up with the expected number of sucesses. And yes, I agree the middle has to be won. That said, I quote the numbers that Mosteller provides.

Comment: Ah, though not here (trusting my intuition....of course, the full computation is easy enough).

Comment: @lulu sorry not sure how to interpret your comments.

Comment: Suppose you play one game only, against the Champ.  What's the expected number of wins?

Comment: so you are saying this is a bernoulli variable and thus it's just $1*c$ ?

Comment: Well, it's just $c$, yes.  And just $m$ for a Mom game.  Now use linearity to get the result.

Comment: OK thanks. still i am confused. If we assume that M and C are bernoulli variables then the probability of losing is 0. Hence probability of winning M-C-M would be $1*m + 0*(1-m) + 1*c+0*(1-c) + 1*m+0*(1-m) = m+c+m=2*m + c$. Not sure how you would formalize this otherwise. Would you say that M is the random variable of winning mom? and C the random varible of winning champ, hence $E[M+C+M] = E[M] + E[C] + E[M] = m+c+m = 2*m+c$ ?

Comment: I don't understand.  The probability of losing is obviously not $0$...why would you say it was?  You agree that the expected number of wins on a Mom game is $m$ and the expected number of wins on a Champ game is $c$, so the expected number of wins on two Mom games is $2m$, and so on.  Linearity is great.

Comment: If you find this confusing for whatever reason, just do it out.  There are $8$ possible outcomes of a three game series...just list them and do the computation to confirm the result derived from Linearity.  It's messy, of course, but not difficult.

Comment: @lulu. no, i dont agree. I defined the probability of winning against mom as $m$. How do you compute the expected number of wins then? Since it's 1 game, it is simply $1*m$ I guess.

Comment: Not following.  1*m is just $m$, why are you insisting on multiplying by $1$?  The expected number of wins in a Mom game is $m$:  it's $1$ with probability $m$ and $0$ otherwise, so $m$.

Comment: @lulu as for the 8 possible outcomes of three games. The three possible actual winning scenarios are outlined in mosteller. Since you have to win the middle game, there are only three possible winning scenarios. My confusing arises from how expected number of wins.

For the C-M-C games

> C-M-C 

W-W-W, W-W-L, L-W-W. 

So, the expected number of wins from this is what?

Comment: I am saying:  write out the expected number of wins explicitly.  I am not looking at the underlying problem, you have asked about the expectation.  What is the probability of winning $3$ games?  Well, that's just $m^2c$, for the MCM series.  And so on.

Comment: That's what I find challenging as you can see.

Comment: You can't write out the $8$ possible outcomes?  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+3*m%5E2*c%2B2*%282*m*c*%281-m%29%2Bm%5E2*%281-c%29%29%2B%28c*%281-m%29%5E2%2B2%28%281-c%29*m*%281-m%29%29%29) is the computation.  But you should do it for yourself.  Work the CMC case for instance (though obviously it follows as you can just switch $m,c$).

Comment: @lulu, I appreciate your effort but instead of explaining it you write some code that is incomprehensible for me to look up now. You might have done everyone a huge bonus favor to state your work -- so others can understand it.

Comment: I have written out the work!  It's just linearity.  That's the best way to do it.  The direct computation works here, but it wouldn't be practical in a $10$ game series. 
 And the computation is just algebra, there is no programming language here.  But, it's clear that my comments are not helping, so I'll stop writing them.  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @lulu, Fine. OK. Thanks. you could have also explained why this "interpretation" is probably not the way to base the reasoning on which choice Sara should pick either C-M-C or M-C-M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation of expected number of wins

The solution claims that the expected number of wins for the MCM pattern is $2m+c$, and the expected number of wins for the CMC pattern is $2c+m$. This is a consequence of linearity of expectation.

Let's focus on the MCM pattern for now. Let $X_1$ be a random variable which is equal to $1$ if Sara wins her first game, and $0$ if she loses. Similarly, define $X_2$ and $X_3$ to be $0$ or $1$ based on whether Sara wins her second and third games. This means the total number of wins is $X_1+X_2+X_3$. Therefore,
$$
\text{expected # of wins}=E[X_1+X_2+X_3]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+E[X_3]
$$
We can distribute the $E$ over addition, because this is one of the most basic properties of expected value. All that remains is to compute $E[X_i]$, for $i\in \{1,2,3\}$. This is easy because each random variable can only take the values $0$ or $1$. For example,
$$
E[X_1]=0\cdot P(X_1=0)+1\cdot P(X_1=1)=0\cdot (1-m)+1\cdot m=m
$$
Similarly, $E[X_2]=c$ and $E[X_3]=m$. Putting this altogether, the expected number wins is $2m+c$ for the MCM pattern, as they claimed.

#### Why expected number of wins is not important

In order to win two games in a row, Sara needs to win the middle game, and must win one of the other two games as well. Since the middle game is so crucial, it is better to have the middle game be as easy to win as possible. Therefore, the preferred schedule is Champ, Mom, Champ.

It may be surprising that Sara would prefer playing more matches against the more skilled player. And it is true that Sara will win more matches, on average, if Sara chooses Mom-Champ-Mom. However, with the MCM setup, it is likely that Sara will get the pattern Win-Lose-Win, which is a lot of wins, but which is useless towards Sara's goal. Basically, expected value is useless because this only tells us the average number of wins, but the number of wins does not necessarily correlate with getting two wins in a row.

#### Rigorous solution

Let $x$ be the probability of winning against the first opponent (so $x$ is the odds of winning aginst either mom or champ), and let $y$ be the probability of winning against the second opponent ($y$ is whatever $x$ is not). In order to win two games in a row, Sara must win the middle match, and then must not lose both first and last matches. Therefore,
$$
P(\text{Sara wins two in a row})=y\cdot (1-(1-x)^2)=yx(2-x)
$$
Now, let $m$ be the probability Sara wins against Mom, and let $c$ be the probability Sara wins against the Champ. In the case where Sara plays Mom-Champ-Mom, the probability is $c\cdot m(2-m)$ and in the case of Champ-Mom-Champ, the probabilty is $m\cdot c(2-c)$. Since $c>m$, it is clear that $cm(2-m)>cm(2-c)$, which proves that Champ-Mom-Champ is preferable.